# Resolving incorrect function at compile time BUG?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 and .NET 4.5 here is the code.

```
void Test(Action a) { }
void Test(Func<int> a) { }
void TestError()
{
    bool throwException = true;
    //Resolves to Test(Action a)
    Test(() =>
    {
    });
    //Resolves to Test(Action a)
    Test(() =>
    {
        if (throwException) throw new Exception();
    });
    //Resolves to Test(Func<int> a)
    //(This seems like a bug since there is no return value)
    Test(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception();
    });
    //Resolves to Test(Action a)
    //(With warning unreachable code detected)
    Test(() =>
    {
        throw new Exception();
        return; //unreachable code detected
    });
}
```

It appears the last function call is incorrectly resolving to Func instead of Action and it has something to do with unconditionally throwing an exception.

Is this a BUG?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you add `return;` after the throw statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems reasonable to me that both are valid candidates. In other words, I think it's fine to have a conversion of `() => { throw new Exception(); }` to both `Func<int>` and `Action`. In both cases the end of the method is unreachable - it would be entirely valid to put that into a normal named method like this:

```
public int GoBang()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

and then write:

```
Func<int> foo = GoBang;
```

So, the conversions from the lambda expression to both `Func<int>` and `Action` are valid. We now need to pick which method to use. This is specified in spec section 7.5.3.2 (better function member), which includes this:

> For at least one argument, the conversion from E<sub>x</sub> to P<sub>x</sub> is better than the conversion from from E<sub>x</sub> to Q<sub>x</sub>

At this point, section 7.5.3.3 (better conversion from expression) kicks in:

> C<sub>1</sub> is a *better conversion* than C<sub>2</sub> if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - [...]
> - E is an anonymous function, T<sub>1</sub> is either a delegate type D<sub>1</sub> or an expression tree type Expression<D<sub>1</sub>>, T<sub>2</sub> is either a delegate type D<sub>2</sub> or an expression tree type Expression<D<sub>2</sub>>, and one of the following holds:
>
>   - [...]
>   - D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> have identical parameter lists, and one of the following holds:
>   - D<sub>1</sub> has a return type Y, and D<sub>2</sub> is void returning.

So that's why `Func<int>` is preferred over `Action`... the compiler's doing the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, that's curious that it doesn't complain about the ambiguity. http://ideone.com/Bz2i5F - If you remvoe the Func, it works just fine, it just resolves to the Action instead.

Comment: The relevant section of the C# 5 spec appears to be 7.5.3.3, which states that a conversion of an anonymous function to a delegate type D1 is better than a delegate type D2 with identical parameter lists if "D1 has a return type Y, and D2 is void returning".

Comment: This just raises the question of why the second resolves to `Action` though.  It doesn't return a value, so both are candidates, and the same line in the specs should apply to both examples, no?

Comment: @Servy: No, in the second case the end of the lambda expression is reachable, so it *isn't* convertible to `Func<int>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'ved edited to add another example based on Will A and it seems to go against this reasoning.  Thanks.

Comment: @AaronStainback: No, it argues *for* this reasoning. When you've got a plain `return;` statement, that's no longer convertible to `Func<int>`.